# Reactive deceleration in svelte not working as expected

Tags: svelte

I am trying to create a TextAreaAutosize component which returns a textarea which adjust its height automatically when need to.

I wanted to run onHeightChange function when height changes so i used svelte reactive statements($:) so that whenever change in height, that piece of code run.

**App.svelte**

```html
<script>
  import TextArea from "./TextAreaAutosize.svelte";
  let val, ref;
</script>

<TextArea 
  bind:value={val}  
  bind:ref={ref} 
  style={"height: 90px; maxHeight=40"} 
  minRows={4}
 />
```

**TextAreaAutosize.svelte**

```html
<script context="module">
  import calculateNodeHeight from './calculateNodeHeight.js'
  let uid = 0;
  const noop = () => {};
</script>

<script>
  export let value = '';
  export let style;
  export let useCacheForDOMMeasurements = false;
  export let minRows = -Infinity;
  export let maxRows = +Infinity;
  export let onHeightChange = noop;
  export let ref = null;

  let refConfig = {
    _uid: uid++
  }

  let state = {
    height: 0,
    minHeight: -Infinity,
    maxHeight: +Infinity
  }

  // runs when change in height
  $: if(state.height){

    //block 1

    console.log('height changed')
    onHeightChange(refConfig)

  }

  // resizes element on initial mount or whenever change in value
  $:if(ref || value){

     //block 2

    _resizeComponent()

  }

  // function for resizing textarea when required
  function _resizeComponent(){
    if(!ref){
      return;
    }

    const refHeight = calculateNodeHeight(
      ref,
      refConfig._uid,
      useCacheForDOMMeasurements,
      minRows,
      maxRows
    );

    const {
      height,
      minHeight,
      maxHeight,
      rowCount,
      valueRowCount
    } = refHeight;

    refConfig.rowCount = rowCount;
    refConfig.valueRowCount = rowCount;

    if(
      state.height !== height ||
      state.maxHeight !== maxHeight ||
      state.minHeight !== minHeight
    ){
      state = {height, minHeight, maxHeight}
    }
  }

</script>

<textarea 
  bind:value={value} 
  bind:this={ref} 
  style={`${style};height: ${state.height}px;`}
  on:click
  on:change  
  class={$$props.class}
/>
```

In this component the block 1 should run whenever the state.height changes. but it doesn't run at all. But when i place it after the block2 it runs whenever there is change in state.height

when value of textarea change block2 run and calls _resizeComponent which then update state with new height if needed. which should trigger block1 if height change. but it triggers that block only if i place it after block2

i am not able to understand why this behaviour in my code. Statements in block1 should run whenever change in state.height irrespective of order of reactive statements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Svelte can't determine, from analysing that code, that the second block could affect the value of `state`. So it doesn't reorder the blocks to run the second one first. (It can't just keep re-running the reactive blocks if there are unexpected changes at the end; that way lies infinite loops.)

If instead of just `_resizeComponent()` it was `state = _resizeComponent()`, and the function was changed accordingly, that would change. Alternatively, just reorder the blocks manually.

Incidentally, there's an easier way to get an auto-resizing textarea: https://svelte.dev/repl/40f4c7846e6f4052927ff5f9c5271b66?version=3.6.8